# What does having two asterisk ** in Objective-C mean?

Tags: objective-c, pointers

I understand having one asterisk * is a pointer, what does having two ** mean?

I stumble upon this from the documentation:

```
- (NSAppleEventDescriptor *)executeAndReturnError:(NSDictionary **)errorInfo
```

Comment: Wild guess: a pointer to pointer? :)

Comment: yeah i was guessing that too, but I couldn't find any confirmation from google. :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's a pointer to a pointer, just like in C (which, despite its strange square-bracket syntax, Objective-C is based on):

```
char c;
char *pc = &c;
char **ppc = &pc;
char ***pppc = &ppc;
```

and so on, ad infinitum (or until you run out of variable space).

It's often used to pass a pointer to a function that must be able to change the pointer itself (such as re-allocating memory for a variable-sized object).

=====

Following your request for a sample that shows how to use it, here's some code I wrote for another post which illustrates it. It's an `appendStr()` function which manages its own allocations (you still have to free the final version). Initially you set the string (`char *`) to NULL and the function itself will allocate space as needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void appendToStr (int *sz, char **str, char *app) {
    char *newstr;
    int reqsz;

    /* If no string yet, create it with a bit of space. */

    if (*str == NULL) {
        *sz = strlen (app) + 10;
        if ((*str = malloc (*sz)) == NULL) {
            *sz = 0;
            return;
        }
        strcpy (*str, app);
        return;
    }
```

```
    /* If not enough room in string, expand it. We could use realloc
       but I've kept it as malloc/cpy/free to ensure the address
       changes (for the program output). */

    reqsz = strlen (*str) + strlen (app) + 1;
    if (reqsz > *sz) {
        *sz = reqsz + 10;
        if ((newstr = malloc (*sz)) == NULL) {
            free (*str);
            *str = NULL;
            *sz = 0;
            return;
        }
        strcpy (newstr, *str);
        free (*str);
        *str = newstr;
    }

    /* Append the desired string to the (now) long-enough buffer. */

    strcat (*str, app);
}
```

```
static void dump(int sz, char *x) {
    if (x == NULL)
        printf ("%8p   [%2d]   %3d   [%s]\n", x, sz, 0, "");
    else
        printf ("%8p   [%2d]   %3d   [%s]\n", x, sz, strlen (x), x);
}

static char *arr[] = {"Hello.", " My", " name", " is", " Pax",
                      " and"," I", " am", " old."};

int main (void) {
    int i;
    char *x = NULL;
    int sz = 0;

    printf (" Pointer   Size   Len   Value\n");
    printf (" -------   ----   ---   -----\n");
    dump (sz, x);
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr[0]); i++) {
        appendToStr (&sz, &x, arr[i]);
        dump (sz, x);
    }
}
```

The code outputs the following. You can see how the pointer changes when the currently allocated memory runs out of space for the expanded string (at the comments):

```
 Pointer   Size   Len   Value
 -------   ----   ---   -----
# NULL pointer here since we've not yet put anything in.
     0x0   [ 0]     0   []

# The first time we put in something, we allocate space (+10 chars).
0x6701b8   [16]     6   [Hello.]
0x6701b8   [16]     9   [Hello. My]
0x6701b8   [16]    14   [Hello. My name]

# Adding " is" takes length to 17 so we need more space.
0x6701d0   [28]    17   [Hello. My name is]
0x6701d0   [28]    21   [Hello. My name is Pax]
0x6701d0   [28]    25   [Hello. My name is Pax and]
0x6701d0   [28]    27   [Hello. My name is Pax and I]

# Ditto for adding " am".
0x6701f0   [41]    30   [Hello. My name is Pax and I am]
0x6701f0   [41]    35   [Hello. My name is Pax and I am old.]
```

In that case, you pass in `**str` since you need to be able to change the `*str` value.

=====

Or the following, which does an unrolled bubble sort (oh, the shame!) on strings that aren't in an array. It does this by directly exchanging the addresses of the strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void sort (char **s1, char **s2, char **s3, char **s4, char **s5) {
    char *t;

    if (strcmp (*s1, *s2) > 0) { t = *s1; *s1 = *s2; *s2 = t; }
    if (strcmp (*s2, *s3) > 0) { t = *s2; *s2 = *s3; *s3 = t; }
    if (strcmp (*s3, *s4) > 0) { t = *s3; *s3 = *s4; *s4 = t; }
    if (strcmp (*s4, *s5) > 0) { t = *s4; *s4 = *s5; *s5 = t; }

    if (strcmp (*s1, *s2) > 0) { t = *s1; *s1 = *s2; *s2 = t; }
    if (strcmp (*s2, *s3) > 0) { t = *s2; *s2 = *s3; *s3 = t; }
    if (strcmp (*s3, *s4) > 0) { t = *s3; *s3 = *s4; *s4 = t; }

    if (strcmp (*s1, *s2) > 0) { t = *s1; *s1 = *s2; *s2 = t; }
    if (strcmp (*s2, *s3) > 0) { t = *s2; *s2 = *s3; *s3 = t; }

    if (strcmp (*s1, *s2) > 0) { t = *s1; *s1 = *s2; *s2 = t; }
}

int main (int argCount, char *argVar[]) {
    char *a = "77";
    char *b = "55";
    char *c = "99";
    char *d = "88";
    char *e = "66";

    printf ("Unsorted: [%s] [%s] [%s] [%s] [%s]\n", a, b, c, d, e);
    sort (&a,&b,&c,&d,&e);
    printf ("  Sorted: [%s] [%s] [%s] [%s] [%s]\n", a, b, c, d, e);
    return 0;
}
```

which produces:

```
Unsorted: [77] [55] [99] [88] [66]
  Sorted: [55] [66] [77] [88] [99]
```

Never mind the implementation of sort, just notice that the variables are passed as `char **` so that they can be swapped easily. Any real sort would probably be acting on a true array of data rather than individual variables but that's not the point of the example.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you would use it in code? This still boggles me on how to use it.

Comment: You can use realloc() instead of malloc()+strcpy()+free() in appendToStr().  Also, no reason to be ashamed of bubble sorting 5 elements: bubble sort/insertion sort/selection sort are definitely the fastest algorithms for very small data sets -- most higher-order sort functions switch to one of these as a base case during divide-and-conquer.

Comment: @Adam, the malloc/copy/free was a kludge to ensure the pointer changed, otherwise my debug output may not be as obvious :-) And I'm not *really* ashamed of bubble sort, I actually use it (a slightly optimized and two-direction modification) for mostly-sorted data sets (e.g., an OOo spreadsheet for my business where transactions sorted by date where you add a small number of new ones at the end but they may be out of order) and it works better than many others in that situation.

Comment: But mostly-sorted datasets, very small datasets and homework assignments are probably the only three places I'd use it.

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation. Is running out of space the ONLY reason we may need to change the pointer? Also what defines the *currently allocated memory* ? Do all objects have the same initial allocated memory size or it varies based on type or something?

Comment: Also why **don't** *mutable* objects such as `NSMutableData` or `NSMutableArray`, which may also expand and run out of space use **?

Answer (score 3):

**Pointer to Pointer**

The definition of "pointer" says that it's a special variable that stores the *address* of another variable (not the value). That other variable can very well be a pointer. This means that it's perfectly legal for a pointer to be pointing to another pointer.

Let's suppose we have a pointer `p1` that points to yet another pointer `p2` that points to a character `c`. In memory, the three variables can be visualized as :

[image]

So we can see that in memory, pointer `p1` holds the address of pointer `p2`. Pointer `p2` holds the address of character `c`.

So `p2` is pointer to character `c`, while `p1` is pointer to `p2`. Or we can also say that `p2` is a pointer to a pointer to character `c`.

Now, in code `p2` can be declared as :

> char *p2 = &c;

But `p1` is declared as :

> char **p1 = &p2;

So we see that `p1` is a double pointer (i.e. pointer to a pointer to a character) and hence the two *s in declaration.

Now,

- `p1` is the address of `p2` i.e. 5000
- `*p1` is the value held by `p2` i.e. 8000
- `**p1` is the value at 8000 i.e. `c`
  I think that should pretty much clear the concept, lets take a small example :

Source: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/01/advanced-c-pointers/

**For some of its use cases:**

This is usually used to pass a pointer to a function that must be able to change the pointer itself, some of its use cases are:

- Such as handling errors, it allows the receiving method to control what the pointer is referencing to. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765519/why-passing-error-instead-of-error-in-cocoa-programming) question
- For creating an opaque struct i.e. so that others won't be able to allocate space. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610518/why-is-that-for-sqlite3-open-we-use-double-pointer-and-for-sqlite3-prepare-we/36610786?noredirect=1#comment60819087_36610786) question
- In case of memory expansion mentioned in the other answers of this question.

<sub>feel free to edit/improve this answer as I am learning:]</sub>

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

In C pointers and arrays can be treated the same, meaning e.g. char* is a string (array of chars). If you want to pass an array of arrays (e.g. many strings) to a function you can use char**.

Comment: With one difference: sizeof (char[]) != sizeof (char*) : plenty of people have been bitten by this.

Answer (score 1):

(reference: more iOS 6 development)

> In Objective-C methods, arguments, including object pointers, are
>   passed by value, which means that the called method gets its own copy
>   of the pointer that was passed in. So if the called method wants to
>   change the pointer, as opposed to the data the pointer points to, you
>   need another level of indirection. Thus, the pointer to the pointer.