# & with variable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why passing &error instead of error in Cocoa programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765519/why-passing-error-instead-of-error-in-cocoa-programming)

I have a question for which I cannot seem to find an answer...

I am using the SBJsonParser and there is a line of code I find puzzling:

```
NSError *error;
self.jsonData = [jsonParser objectWithString:responseString error:&error];
```

What is the & in front of the error parameter? (&error)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Objective-C, just like in C, `&` is the "address-of operator" and it returns the address of its argument. To find out more about it, I recommend you read [this short chapter](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter5/arrays_and_address_of.html) from The C Book.

Here's an example of how the operator is used, to get a better idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// define a function that takes a pointer to an integer as argument
void change_value_of_int(int* int_to_change) {
    // change the value to which the argument points
    *int_to_change = 5;
}

int main() {
    // create a stack variable
    int test_int = 10;

    // pass the address of test_int to the function defined earlier
    change_value_of_int(&test_int);

    // now the value of test_int is 5
    printf("%d\n", test_int);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the `change_value_of_int()` function expects the first parameter to be a *pointer* to an int, not an int, so you can't call it with `change_value_of_int(test_int)`. You must send it the *address* of the `test_int` variable, not the variable itself (because if you send a copy of the variable, it can't change it).

Same thing with the `NSError*` example. `jsonParser` expects the *address* of a `NSError*`, not a `NSError*`, therefore the method is defined as:

```
- (id)objectWithString:(NSString*)jsonrep error:(NSError**)error;
```

Take a look at [the header file](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/source/browse/trunk/Source/SBJSON.h?r=549#51) and at [the implementation](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/source/browse/trunk/Source/SBJSON.m?r=549#82) to see how it is used. The value of your `error` (`*error` = the value of the thing pointed to by the `error` argument) becomes the return value of `[errorTrace lastObject]`.

Comment: Thanks, this totally explains it for me. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 5):

It's the address of operator, found in C, C++ and Objective-C.

In your example, `&error` yields a `NSError **` (that is, a pointer to a pointer).

This is common in C (and, by extension, Objective-C): pass-by-reference is simulated with pointers, which means you have to pass the address of the object you want to modify (in this case, another pointer) to a function.

Answer (score 0):

`&` is the address operator.
real quick lesson, all objects in Objective-C are pointers, which makes thing easy, because you know the level of indifference of everything, `id` is a special case, which a pointer to any object, without specifying class.

pointer to a pointer is most often used when returning an error, that is passed as a parameter to a method.

```
-(void)doSomething:(NSError**)err
{
    //we have an error, return it.
    *err = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"custom Domain" code:42 userInfo:nil];

}
```

then use the method with:

```
    NSError * err = nil;
    [self doSomething:&err];
    if(err)
    {
        NSLog(@"we have an error in domain: %@",[err domain]);
    }
```

which outputs:

> we have an error in domain: custom
>   Domain

this is especially useful when you are returning something, as you can only return one value in C. This is exceptionally common is vanilla C and C++, but not used that much in Objective-C.

Comment: In Cocoa, you should always check the direct return value before trying to use the error object. Never use `if(err)` to determine whether the method failed.

Comment: yeah, you are correct, that would be a good practice.