# Why is that for sqlite3_open we use double pointer ** and for sqlite3_prepare we use pointer *

Tags: c, pointers, sqlite, mutable

Please correct me where I understood wrong.

I read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/833124/5175709 and what I understood was that since the object could expand and run out of space then the memory location my also change.But here two sqlite3 syntaxes are referencing to the object differently. WHY?

sqlite3_open we have: `sqlite3 **ppDb`

```
SQLITE_API int SQLITE_STDCALL sqlite3_open(
  const char *filename,   /* Database filename (UTF-8) */
  sqlite3 **ppDb          /* OUT: SQLite db handle */
```

And for sqlite3_prepare we have: `sqlite3 *db`

```
SQLITE_API int SQLITE_STDCALL sqlite3_prepare_v2(
  sqlite3 *db,            /* Database handle */
  const char *zSql,       /* SQL statement, UTF-8 encoded */
  int nByte,              /* Maximum length of zSql in bytes. */
  sqlite3_stmt **ppStmt,  /* OUT: Statement handle */
  const char **pzTail     /* OUT: Pointer to unused portion of zSql */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sqlite3_open` needs to somehow give you a database connection object; i.e. a `sqlite3` object.

To prevent people from accessing the internals, `sqlite3.h` declares `sqlite3` as an opaque struct. This means that you cannot allocate space for a `sqlite3` since you don't know what it holds; the SQLite library must allocate it for you and give you a pointer to it (`sqlite3*`).

So now we have a hypothetical function `sqlite3* sqlite3_open(...);`, which opens a DB and returns a pointer to the connection object. But hold on; what if an error occurs? We could return `NULL`, but how is the developer supposed to distinguish a "database doesn't exist" error from a "database is read only", "database is corrupted", or other errors?

So instead, `sqlite3_open` returns an integer return code, and writes the connection pointer to the memory that the `ppDB` parameter points to if opening succeeded.

`sqlite3_open` is usually used like this:

```
sqlite3* myDB;
int status = sqlite3_open("/path/to/db", &myDB);
if(status != SQLITE_OK) {
    // error occured
    return;
}
// sqlite3_open wrote a database pointer to myDB, use it here
status = sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDB, "SELECT * FROM whatever", -1, NULL, NULL);
// ...
```

Comment: Excellent answer C32, thanks. So you are saying the only reason we are doing this is for protection? So if there is an error the sqlite3* would be pointing to `nil`?What about the expansion of memory? I am still confused on that. Can you please elaborate on that as well?

Comment: @asma22 The only way to detect if an error occurs is by looking at the return value; [SQLite will still write a database pointer even if it could not be opened](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) (likely so that you can get an error message from it). Because the exact structure of the `sqlite3` structure is hidden from the program using SQLite, SQLite is free to add or remove fields from it (which may change the amount of memory it uses) without breaking the API or ABI.