# Why don't mutable objects require double pointers?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, memory, mutable

I read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/833124/5175709 and some other questions. From what I understand it's that since the object could expand and run out of space then the memory location my also change. I never understood why we shouldn't use `**` for `NSMutableData` or `NSMutableArray` since they could also expand with any `add`ing or `append`ing and be in need of more space.

Please correct me where I understood wrong. I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object references are only required to be single pointers as it does not relate to the memory *they manage*.  For example the `NSData` class (the super class of `NSMutableData`) probably contains the following instance variables:

(this is conjecture as I don't have access to the source code)

```
@interface NSData : NSObject
{
    void *_data;
    NSUInteger _length;
}
@end
```

If the `NSMutableData` subclass wants to add to the data buffer it can perform a `realloc()` on `_data` and increase `_length`.

The pointer to the `NSMutableData` object itself does not change at all and the memory it manages is hidden from the developer.

Comment: Thanks, so they are in fact using a pointer to pointer, but we only deal with the reference?

Comment: @asma22 Philosophically speaking, yes, but not in the language sense of `Object **`.  For example dereferencing an `NSMutableData` pointer won't necessarily point to the `_data` member; the class would work just as well if `_length` came before `_data`.

Answer (score 3):

`NSMutableArray *` and `NSMutableData *` are not pointers directly to the contained data. They are something more along this line:

```
struct MutableData {
    void * data;
    void (*appendBytes)(void * bytes);
    // etc.
};
```

When they need to reallocate for expansion (or contraction), there is an internal pointer that they are manipulating. You, as a user of the containing instance, don't interact with that.