# Conversion error OBJ-C to Swift 3

Tags: objective-c, swift, ezaudio

I am trying to convert a EZAudio (https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio) Objective-C Library to Swift 3. I am doing the "EZAudioPlayFileExample" part in it.

## Objective-C

```
- (void)openFileWithFilePathURL:(NSURL*)filePathURL
{
    self.audioFile = [EZAudioFile audioFileWithURL:filePathURL];
    self.filePathLabel.text = filePathURL.lastPathComponent;

    //
    // Plot the whole waveform
    //
    self.audioPlot.plotType = EZPlotTypeBuffer;
    self.audioPlot.shouldFill = YES;
    self.audioPlot.shouldMirror = YES;

    //
    // Get the audio data from the audio file
    //
    __weak typeof (self) weakSelf = self;
    [self.audioFile getWaveformDataWithCompletionBlock:^(float **waveformData,
                                                         int length)
    {
        [weakSelf.audioPlot updateBuffer:waveformData[0]
                          withBufferSize:length];
    }];
}
```

## Swift 3

```
func openFileWithFilePathURL(filePathURL: NSURL) {
        self.audioFile = EZAudioFile(url: filePathURL as URL!)

        //
        // Plot the whole waveform
        //
        self.plot.plotType = .buffer
        self.plot.shouldFill = true
        self.plot.shouldMirror = true

        //
        // Get the audio data from the audio file
        //
        weak var weakSelf = self
        self.audioFile.getWaveformData(completionBlock: {(_ waveformData: Float, _ length: Int) -> Void in
            weakSelf?.plot.updateBuffer(waveformData[0], withBufferSize: length) // error in this line as Float as no subscript members
        })
    }
```

I know Float parameter have no subscript members like [0]. But I want to convert the Objective-C code. OR anyone here use this library's Swift version. NOTE: I want the "EZAudioPlayFileExample" in it.

Comment: Why you want to convert the library to swift you can use objective C libraries in swift project by using bridging headers

Comment: @AravindAR you are correct I am doing with bridging header. Above code is coming from implementation part (ViewController.m). So I need convert that to Swift

Comment: "I know Float parameter have no subscript members like [0]" In Objective-C, it's `float **waveformData`, notice the two `*`.

Comment: @Larme Then what will be the code in swift 3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833112/what-does-having-two-asterisk-in-objective-c-mean + have a look at the sample method `executeAndReturnError:` (it's an official method in the macOS SDK) and how is it declared in Swift with ` AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer` and related stuff to know how to use it in Swift.

Comment: @AlwinLazar I have added an answer and hope it might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`float **waveformData` is actually an `unsafemutablepointer`. So you have to use `unsafemutablepointer` in swift 3.0. 
You can use unsafemutablepointer in swift like

```
UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>>
```

You could use like

```
self.audioFile.getWaveformData(completionBlock: {(_ waveformData: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>>, _ length: Int) -> Void in
            weakSelf?.plot.updateBuffer(waveformData[0], withBufferSize: length)  
        })
```

I have just downloaded an older version swift implementation of EZAudio and converted to swift 3.0. It is available at this [link](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio-Swift)
I don't know where this will help you or not but you may build on top of this.
You could also refer to this [issue](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio/issues/198) being reported on the gitHub page